# Why doesn't the .bind() method work with a frame widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, events, tkinter

This code is an attempt to bind a command to a frame, ie. when the "Escape" key is pressed, the window should be destroyed.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root=Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

frame1=ttk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack()

def Exit(event):
    root.destroy()

frame1.bind("<Escape>", Exit)

root.mainloop()
```

if `frame1.bind()` is replaced by `root.bind()`, the code works as I would expect it to. Why doesn't what I've written above work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bind works, but the event will only trigger if the frame has focus, and by default a frame does not have the keyboard focus.

Try setting the focus with `frame1.focus_set()`

Comment: Ah, fantastic. So does changing the focus affect anything else? What sort of widgets normally have focus?

Comment: would wigits having the `take_focus()` method applied mess this up?

Comment: Changing the focus doesn't affect anything else. Widgets that take focus are any widgets that take input -- text widget, entry widget, etc. The `take_focus()` method doesn't "mess" things up per se, but it certainly can change the behavior as it is documented to do.

Comment: Yeah, I've just reread all the documentation with my new knowledge and the problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: This is good, @Bryan. Maybe you also know why do key events (bindings) stop working after a **tkMessageBox** is displayed? (Mouse button events still work, though.) Re-focusing the frame (as you have suggested) doesn't help.

Comment: @Apostolos: I don't understand your question. If you need help with something, click the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: Indeed, I have posted a question on the subject. Please check "Tkinter tkMessageBox disables Tkinter key bindings" at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983443/tkinter-tkmessagebox-disables-tkinter-key-bindings and see if you can contribute. Two other persons were able to reproduce the problem.  I have only half-solved it.