# Tkinter Frame Not Recognizing Keypresses

Tags: python, tkinter

This question is NOT a duplicate of this question: [Why doesn't the .bind() method work with a frame widget in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923167/why-doesnt-the-bind-method-work-with-a-frame-widget-in-tkinter)

As you can see, I set the focus to the current frame in my game_frame() method.

I'm writing a Chip-8 emulator in Python and using Tkinter for my GUI. The emulator is running, but I can't get Tkinter to recognize keypresses. Here is my code:

```
def game_frame(self):
    self.screen = Frame(self.emulator_frame, width=640, height=320)
    self.screen.focus_set()
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.screen, width=640, height=320, bg="black")
    self._root.bind("<KeyPress-A>", self.hello)
    for key in self.CPU.KEY_MAP.keys():
        print(key)
        self.screen.bind(key, self.hello)
    self.screen.pack()
    self.canvas.pack()

def hello(self, event):
    if event.keysym in self.CPU.KEY_MAP.keys():
        self.CPU.keypad[self.CPU.KEY_MAP[event.keysym]] = 1
        self.CPU.key_pressed = True
        self.CPU.pc += 2
    sys.exit()

def run_game(self, event):
    self.game_frame()
    self.CPU.load_rom("TANK")
    while True:
        self._root.update()
        self.after(0, self.CPU.emulate_cycle)
```

Could you please help me figure out what's going wrong? I think it might have something to do with my game loop interfering with the key bindings, but I'm not sure. The hello method never gets called when I run the game because the program continues to run in an infinite loop and never exits, regardless of what key is pressed. Thank you!

Comment: what does `self.hello` returns ??

Comment: self.hello doesn't return anything, but it modifies the game state and then causes the program to terminate.

Comment: what is self._root? Is it truly the root window, or some other frame? Are you aware you are binding to the capital "A"? Are you certain this doesn't work when you press shift-a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be due to two things. Without seeing all your code it's impossible to say for sure.

For one, you are binding to a capital "A" rather than a lowercase "a" -- have you testing that the binding works or not when you press a capital A?

Also, you are using `after` and `update` incorrectly. You may be starving the event loop, preventing it from processing key presses. The right way to run a function periodically is to have a function that (re)schedules itself.

```
class CPU_Class():
    ...
    def run_cycle(self):
        self.emulate_cycle()
        self._root.after(1, self.run_cycle)
```

Two things to note:

1. don't use `after(0, ...)` -- you need to give tkinter at least a ms or so to process other events.
2. the run_cycle function is responsible for running one cycle, and then scheduling the next cycle to run in the future.

Once you do that, you no longer need your `while` loop. You can simply call `run_cycle` once, and that will start the CPU running.

Comment: I revised my event loop per your suggestions and the window seems to be recognizing keypresses now, so thanks for that! I'm still a tad confused though, what exactly did you mean when you said that I was starving my event loop?

Comment: @Danny: in essence, you were creating more events than it could process in a given amount of time.