# Simple bind function doesn't work in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, bind

I'm currently creating an adventure game and I want to bind alt+a to my callback. It doesn't do what I want, so I have two questions:

- Is it possible to bind a function to a Label, too?
- Why does this (simplyfied) code doesn't work?

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

dw = tk.Tk()
dw.title('Hearts')

def play(event):
    print('This is the test.')

areal = tk.Frame(master=dw, width=1200, height=600, bg='blue')
areal.pack_propagate(0)
areal.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=bool(dw))
areal.bind("<Alt-A>", play)

dw.mainloop()
```

It doesn't give me an error, but it doesn't do anything when I click the Frame and afterwards press alt+a. What is wrong here?

**EDIT:**

```
import tkinter as tk

def go_fwd(event):
    areal.focus_set()
    print(event.x, event.y)

dw = tk.Tk()
dw.title('Adventure')


areal = tk.Frame(master=dw, width=20000, height=600, bg='blue')
areal.pack_propagate(0)
areal.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=bool(dw)-100)
areal.focus_set()
dw.bind("<Alt-A>", go_fwd)

enter = tk.Frame(master=dw, width=20000, height=100, bg='cyan')
enter.pack(fill=tk.X)

enterentry = tk.Text(master=enter, width=100, height=4, bg='white')
enterentry.pack()
enterbutton = tk.Button(master=enter, text='Senden', bg='red')
enterbutton.pack()

dw.mainloop()
```

Here is the complete code.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16923167/7432

Comment: I will edit my answer, so you can see my complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to bind a function to a Label, too?

You can bind to any widget you want. However, if you bind key events, the bindings will only work if the widget has focus. By default, most widgets other than `Entry` and `Text` don't get focus unless you explicitly set the focus to them.

**Note:** only one widget can have keyboard focus at a time.

You can also set a binding to the root window, which will cause it to fire no matter what widget has focus.

For a more thorough explanation of how key bindings are processed, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11542200/7432

> Why does this (simplyfied) code doesn't work?

It doesn't work the way you expect because the binding is on a Frame widget, but that widget doesn't have the keyboard focus. You could give it focus with something like this:

```
areal.focus_set()
```

Or, you could only give it focus after you click on the frame, by creating a binding on a mouse click:

```
areal.bind("<1>", lambda event: areal.focus_set())
```

**Note:** you are binding to a capital "A", so make sure when you test that you're pressing <kbd>control-alt-a</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to `dw` instead of your frame.

So, you can do `dw.bind("<Alt-A>", play)`.

A minor note, `Alt-A` will bind to the *uppercase* A as expected, so you'd have to click `Alt+Shift+A` on your keyboard. Doing `Alt+A` on your keyboard won't work, you'd have to bind to `Alt-a` for this to work.

The main window has keyboard focus. Or, alternatively you can leave the bind on the frame and just do `areal.focus_set()` to set the focus to the frame.

Comment: But why does it work fine with left-click and not with alt+a

Comment: @ErichSchmidt: key events go to the widget that has focus. Button events go to the widget under the cursor. That's why the binding for a button seems to behave differently than the binding for a key.

Comment: @BryanOakley: How do I execute my callback with a key?

Comment: @ErichSchmidt: follow the instructions in this answer. Either give focus to the widget with the binding, or put the binding on a widget with focus. By default, clicking on a frame does not give it focus, so a third solution is to add another binding to the frame that sets the focus when it is clicked on.