# Python Tkinter Keybinds and Buttons blocking each other?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, bind

I've got a piece of code similar to this:

```
def create_main(self):

    self.bind("<Left>", lambda e:self.function())
    self.button1 = Button(self, ...)
    self.button1.grid(row=0, column =0)

    #furtherbuttons...

def function(self):
    print('test')
```

The Problem I've got with this code is that the function never gets called if I press left. I tried it with different buttons and the mouse, mouse buttons always work just fine but the keyboard does nothing.

I read something about buttons blocking the bind action, but no solution to this problem.

Comment: Please add a bit more and post an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Buttons don't block the bind action. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16923167/7432

Comment: I'm assuming "self" is a frame? You probably need to bind to the root.

Comment: Hello Veit, and welcome to the site.  We like to keep questions to the point here, so I trimmed yours down a bit.  If you aren't happy with it, feel free to edit it again.

Comment: Thanks for all those kind response!
Sorry, i forgot to mention that this is the class for the Frame, so yes self is a Frame.
Binding the actions to the root is probably the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an MCVE that works with 3.6.1 on Win10.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def handle(event=None):
    print(event)
    return 'break'

root.bind('<Left>', handle)
tk.Button(root, text='button', command=handle)
root.mainloop()
```

Both <-- and left click print event arg.  No interference or blocking.