# Tkinter tkMessageBox disables Tkinter key bindings

Tags: python, events, tkinter, keyboard-events, messagebox

Here's a very simple example:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

def quit(event):
  exit()

root = Tk()
root.bind("<Escape>", quit)
#tkMessageBox.showinfo("title", "message")
root.mainloop()
```

If I run the code **exactly** as it is, the program will terminate when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is hit. Now, if I un-comment the `tkMessageBox` line, the binding is "lost" after closing the message box, i.e. pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> won't do anything anymore. This is happening in Python 2.7. Can you please verify if this is happening also to you? And let me know about your Python version.

---

Here is a way to "by-pass" the problem. It's a different approach, but it might help:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

def msg_test():
  tkMessageBox.showinfo("title", "message")

def quit(event):
  exit()

root = Tk()
root.bind("<Escape>", quit)
btn = Button(root, text="Check", command=msg_test); btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Using `tkMessageBox` via a button click, doesn't affect key binding, i.e. pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> continues to work.

Comment: Do you focus back into `root` window?

Comment: The issue seems to apply all keyboard events for me as well for python 3.7

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: @BryanOakley I was able to reproduce the issue with both Windows 7 and 10.

Comment: Yes, I applied focus and even repeated the binding. No effect.
I am using Windows 7.

Comment: BTW, here's some more info that might help solving the issue: If I use the `tkMessageBox` in a function that is called when a button is clicked, the display of the message block does not affect the binding. (See my edited question.)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem, you get the bad behavior if you call `tkMessageBox.showInfo()` *before* calling `mainloop`. If that is so, I think this is a known bug in tkinter on windows.

The solution is simple: don't do that. If you need a dialog to show at the very start of your program, use `after` to schedule it to appear after mainloop has started, or call `update` before displaying the dialog.

For example:

```
root = Tk()
root.after_idle(msg_test)
root.mainloop()
```

---

The original bug was reported quite some time ago, and the tk bug database has moved once or twice so I'm having a hard time finding a link to the original issue. Here's one issue from 2000/2001 that mentions it: https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview?name=220431ffff (see the comments at the very bottom of the bug report).

The report claims it was fixed, but maybe it has shown up again, or maybe your version of tkinter is old enough to still have the bug.

Comment: Calling `msg_test()` has no problem when it is done via a button, as I said. But your suggestion of using `root.update()` before `tkMessageBox` is a pleasant revelation!  It works perfectly for as many uses of `tkMessageBox` (directly, in the main body) as one wants! Thanks.